# Content aggregation: Same document library in several subsites into one big document library in main site

Tags: document-library, content-query-web-part, aggregation

Let's say I have a main site collection with three subsites each having one document library:

- MainSite

  - SubSite1 (myDocLib)
  - SubSite2 (myDocLib)
  - SubSite3 (myDocLib)

I want three subsites for security reasons and different design aspects. I now want to **aggregate these three document libraries** on the MainSite. All three lists from the subsites have the same layout.

I could use a content query webpart for that, but I can only select "list of type Document Library" - I cannot select "myDocLib from SubSite1, myDocLib from SubSite2, myDocLib from Subsite3". Also the content query webpart does not have the options a normal list has, particularly I need to export the whole aggregated list to Excel (no interactivity, plain export).

What is the best way to do this? Is it somehow possible to create "virtual copies" on the MainSite? In the end all I want is an aggregated view with Excel export ability.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you looked in using the flexibilty of the the Data View Web Part using SharePoint Designer?  I would think that seeing that the rollup, aggregation of data will be feasible seeing that are in the confines for one Site and/or Collection.    The only think I question is the requirement to do an Excel Export.  You won't be able export the data froma data view.

Comment: Yeap I guess it will be CQWP with a custom Excel Export functionality - just thought there might be something easier ;-)

Comment: @DennisG: I have the same question - could you explain how you solved it? Is the CQWP available in SharePoint 2013 Standard, or is it an enterprise feature?